# Estoy utilizando clipboard y en mi local funciona bien pero al subirlo a produccion me muestra un error que en el local no habia

Tags: localhost

[image: Este es mi codigo]

y en producción el error que me sale dice que clipboardItem no esta definido

Comment: Y el error cual es??? Favor colocar el código como texto y agregar la etiqueta javascript

Comment: Este es el error que sale..                                                                              
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ClipboardItem is not a constructor at copyText

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si estás usando Firefox, ten en cuenta que `ClipboardItem` no está disponible